# Record list of application which were active in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-11

I have a strange problem in my PC. My active application keep losing focus randomly. It happens few times a day.

I suspect it's some random task or service or an updator which activates for a second and cause the problem. I am not able to pin-point the culprit yet.

Is their a way to record list of process names had focus during a period. So next time it happens, I can check the list for last 5 minute and find the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to record list of process names had focus during a
> period. So next time it happens, I can check the list for last 5
> minute and find the culprit?

To the best of my knowledge, there is no such log. Apps come and go.

Best approach / good starting approach is with Microsoft SysInternals Process Explorer and Process Monitor (Procmon) to see what is running.

Keep them open and when an app loses focus, try to find it in one of the tools above and if it is related to another process that is causing the loss of focus.

Screen Shots below to illustrate Process Explorer and Procmon.

[image: Process Explorer]

.

[image: Process Monitor]

.